# How can I relate aerosol particle size (2, 5 and 10 microns) with the aerosol index measurement of the Sentinel-5P (TROPOMI) data sets?

Tags: remote-sensing, satellites, weather-satellites, aerosol

I would like to know the relation of aerosol particle size (2,5 and 10 microns) with the measurements from the [Sentinel-5P TROPOMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel-5#Tropomi) data, in the wavelengths 340-380 and 358-388 nm bands.

Comment: just asked in meta: [Satellites, weather-satellites and remote-sensing, why not earth-observation-satellite for the first two and keep the third for non-satellite Q's?](https://earthscience.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1930/6031)